# How to recognize [1,X,X,X,1] repeating pattern in panda serie

Tags: python-3.x

I have a boolean column in a csv file for example:

```
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  0
9  0
10 1
11 0
12 0
13 1
14 0
15 1
```

You can see here 1 is reapting every 5 lines.
I want to recognize this repeating pattern [1,0,0,0] as soon as the repetition is above 10 in python (I have ~20.000 rows/file).
The pattern can start at any position
How could I manage this in python avoiding if .....

Comment: Cant avoid an `if`

Comment: Why you want to void `if`?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Generate 20000 of 0s and 1s
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 2, 20000))

# Keep indices of 1s
idx = df[df > 0].index

# Check distance of current index with next index whether is 4 or not, 
# Say if position 2 and position 6 is found as 1, so 6 - 2 = 4
found = []
for i, v in enumerate(idx):
    if i == len(idx) - 1:
        break
    next_value = idx[i + 1]
    if (next_value - v) == 4:
        found.append(v)

print(found)
```